# Using navigation to load entity 2 level deep

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, navigation-properties

I have a class

```
public class Level1
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public virtual List<Level2> Level2List {get; set;}
}

public class Level2
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int Level3Id {get; set;}
   public virtual Level3 Level3 {get; set;}
}

public class Level3
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Using navigation properties i could load `List<Level2>` like this

```
var myList = _myLevel1Repository.GetSingle(x=>x.Id == Level1Id, x=>x.Level2List);
```

but how do I load Level3 and its properties that is linked with Level2?

PS: Lazy loading is not possible.
 This is the `Getsingle` function

```
    public T GetSingle(Func<T, bool> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navProps)
    {
        T item = null;
        using (var context = new MyDbContext())
            item = GetFilteredSet(context, navProps).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(where);
        return item;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetSingle` method should be this way:

```
public T GetSingle(Func<T, bool> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navProps)
{
    T item = null;
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = context.Set<T>();

        //Include the navigations properties as part of the query
        if (navProps!= null)
        {
            query = navProps.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
        }
        item = query.Where(where).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return item;
}
```

I don't know what are you doing in the `GetFilteredSet` method, but I guess you can reorganize the code I show above at your convenience. The key to include more than one level of nav. properties in EF is use the `Include` method. When you use this method you are going to load the nav. properties as part of your query (check eager loading section in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eager)). Now, there are two Include methods :

- [DbQuery.Include Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696785(v=vs.113).aspx)

  Whit this method you need to pass the path of the nav. properties you want to load as an string, for example, in your case, it would be:

  ```
  context.Set<Level1>.Include("Level2List.Level3");
  ```
- [DbExtensions.Include  extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.113).aspx)

  This is the method that I use in my above code where you can specify the related objects to include using a lambda expression. IMHO this is the best variant because is strongly typed, and if you change some of the nav. properties name in your entities, you are also going to receive a compilation error(s). In the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.113).aspx) I share above, you can see all the patterns you can use to include different levels of nav. properties.

  ```
  context.Set<Level1>.Include(l1=>l1.Level2List.Select(l2=>l2.Level3));
  ```

Returning to the initial problem, now you can use your `GetSingle` method to include more than one level this way:

```
var entity= _myLevel1Repository.GetSingle(x=>x.Id == Level1Id, x=>x.Level2List.Select(l2=>l2.Level3));
```

Comment: Exactly, the first `Include` method I have mentioned is not the best option. You can make a mistake when you are typing the name of one  property or you could also forget rename one of them in the path in case you change the some property name on your model.

Comment: ok like u said i changed my getsingle method. and your last line of code worked like charm. but could you make me one thing clear? In this code `var entity= _myLevel1Repository.GetSingle(x=>x.Id == Level1Id, x=>x.Level2List.Select(l2=>l2.Level3));` why use l2 as in `.select(l2=>l2.Level3)` and not x. And could i go even level deeper?

Comment: Because I need to select a property from the `Level2` entity (which it would be your second level), the `x` is your root. About load levels more deeper, yes you can, in the link I share related to the second `Include` you will find an example: `query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Collection.Select(l2 => l2.Level3Reference))).`

Answer (score 0):

How about using include?

```
 var mylevel1s = _db.Level1(x=>x.Id == Level1Id).Include(x=> x.Level2List.Select(a=>a.Level3));
```